# how to make instagram follower list scroll down and continue follow?

Tags: python, selenium

İ want to make an instagram bot with `python selenium`. I've already made some parts, but the part I'm stuck is I want to scroll down and continue again. The bot will scroll down but it stops and won't continue. Can anybody help me with it? Thanks

```
from selenium import webdriver

import time


browser = webdriver.Chrome()

browser.get("https://www.instagram.com")

time.sleep(3)

username = browser.find_element_by_name("username")
password = browser.find_element_by_name("password")

username.send_keys('instagram user')
password.send_keys('instagram pass')

time.sleep(3)



login = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='react-root']/section/main/article/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/div[4]")
login.click()

time.sleep(3)

browser.get("https://www.instagram.com/mer.ve5427")

time.sleep(3)

login = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='react-root']/section/main/div/header/section/ul/li[2]/a")
login.click()
time.sleep(3)

buttons = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[contains(.,'Follow')]")
for btn in buttons:
     #Use the Java script to click on follow because after the scroll down the buttons will be un clickeable unless you go to it's location
    browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", btn)
    time.sleep(3)

fBody  = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='isgrP']")
scroll = 0
while scroll < 5: # scroll 5 times
    browser.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollTop + arguments[0].offsetHeight;', fBody)
    time.sleep(3)
    scroll += 1
```

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you explain more about what you mean by "continue"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use :-

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, Y)")
```

or else you can also select one element and sendkeys as showed below.

```
label.sendKeys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN);
```